# Visual Studio not creating ".esriAddIn" file

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, add-in, visual-studio

I have an addin that I've been maintaining with Visual Studio 2010 Express for quite some time with no issues. Recently my computer was replaced and Studio 2012 Express was installed. Since that time when I build the addin everything is created except for the .esriAddIn file which is necessary to run the addin with the changes. After looking at the ArcObjects (VB.NET) system requirements I noticed that the only Express version listed was 2010 so I assumed 2012 was the culprit and had our IT department roll me back to 2010. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem and I have been searching for a solution with no success. Anyone have any ideas why every file is built except the .esriAddIn file?

Comment: Did you have the ArcGis templates? The SDK for 2012 is different to 2010. If you have chosen ArcGis template and the .esriAddin isn't created then try reinstalling the 2010 SDK.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but I've never been involved in the setup part of this process. How can I tell if it is 2010 or 2012 SDK. All I see is that the version number is 10.2.3552.

Comment: When 2010 was reinstalled it probably overwrote files that were modified by the original install of the SDK on 2010. You might be able to fix your problem by reinstalling the SDK for 2010 - it will put templates into the Visual Studio folder. If you have to get I.T. to do it for you they shouldn't have a problem.. the wizard detects the installed version and puts the right SDK in the right spot but you may have to uninstall the existing one.

Comment: IT has uninstalled and reinstalled the SDK but I'm still having the same problem. Still creating everything except the .esriAddIn file during build.

Comment: In your solution directory is there a config.esriaddx file, if so can you include that in your question (xxxx out personal info)? Is that referenced in your .vbproj/.vcproj file <AddInContent Include="Config.esriaddinx"> then <Generator>ArcGISAddInHostGenerator</Generator>? Does the tool Implement/Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button or similar?

Comment: The reinstall acutally did do the trick. The problem I was having yesterday was a setting I had changed on that particular project while trying to solve this issue. Once I realized that I set it back and everything is good now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great news. Now stick with Studio 2010. BTW, are you on, or likely to change to, 64 bit windows? Studio Express has  the configuration manager grayed out which can cause problems with 64bit O.S. (did my head in for a while). May not affect an existing project but for new solutions there's a trick to getting it going.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - Yes, I just got upgraded to a 64bit machine. And for something else I had to be able to get into the configuration manager so I had to find some information on turning that option back on. Thanks again for all of your hepl!

Comment: You need to edit your vbproj or vcproj file (notepad, notepad++ etc..) and add a new platform target manually, there's some text on it here http://www.quantcode.com/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=105 but essentially you copy the enclosures for Configuration Condition...Debug/release and Platform.. any CPU then change  'any cpu' to 'x86' and include the line <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>. Instructions for previous versions don't work (no advanced.. checkbox) but this method does work (if you edit it properly), would you like me to expand that to an answer?